# What is a name of this Bernoulli-like process with dependent trials?

Tags: terminology, stochastic-processes, bernoulli-distribution, bernoulli-process

The process is defined similarly to the Bernoulli process composed of $n$ Bernoulli trials. The difference is that the trials are dependent, that is:

$$
P(X_i = 1 | X_1, ..., X_{i-1}) = \frac{m -\sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1} X_j}{m} p ,
$$

where m is a natural number.

Comment: @AdamO I agree. But in this case I guess the process as a whole has no longer such Bernoulli process properties as binomial distribution of number of successes.

Comment: @AdamO But the whole process is not a Bernoulli process. According to Wikipedia _"Bernoulli process is a sequence of **independent identically distributed** Bernoulli trials"_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: @AdamO May you provide me with a quotable source (that it is a BP)? That is different from what I have been taught so far. I guess I need to provide some reference in my thesis then in case my referees were taught the same.

Comment: I think I was confusing discrete time stochastic processes with Bernoulli process. Thanks for encouraging me to dive into notes. I think "Discrete Time Process" is a general framework that can describe the type of sequence you are describing. The probability model, as I said, could be a special case of some autoregressive structure of which I'm unaware. Other than that, I doubt there is a specific title for the probability model you describe.

Comment: This looks like an urn problem.  Assume you have two urns, one (#1) with $m$ blue balls and no red balls and the other (#2) with a single red ball and no blue balls.  You draw from urn 1 with probability $p$ and replace whichever ball is drawn with a red ball.  If you draw from urn 2 you replace the red ball with another red ball (thus maintaining a single red ball in urn 2 at all times)...

Comment: You can see how this would generalize nicely to $(m_i, n_i)$ (blue, red) balls in each urn.  Here we have $(m, 0)$ (blue, red) balls in urn 1 and $(0, n)$ (blue, red) balls in urn 2, where I've arbitrarily set $n=1$ in the example above.  The process stops evolving when all the blue balls are gone, i.e., in state $((0, m), (0, n))$.

I don't know of a name for an urn model with this structure, though, but I'm hardly an expert in this area.